# We want to develop an authentication guard in Angular 2. Can we navigate/redirect to any login url?

Tags: angularjs, guard

Can we navigate/redirect to any login url (different host and application) or must we navigate/redirect only to url's within the routes of our application?

The example from the angular site suggests only application routes are permitted:

---

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

  // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
  this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;

  // Navigate to the login page
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried navigateByUrl()?

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html for usage.

But:
Why you need an "external" URL not part of your application?
I assume best practive would be an external authService instead of an seperate "Login-Page-Application". or such.

e.g.

```js
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router}    from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(protected router: Router, protected authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');

    if (state.url !== '/login' && !this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {redirectTo: state.url}});
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  templateUrl: "app/components/login/login.html"
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router) { }

  loginSuccessful() {
    let redirect = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['redirect'];
    let redirectUrl = redirect != null ? redirect : '/dashboard/';
    console.log('redirect to: ' + redirect);
    this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
  }

}
```